# separate one data from one column by repeated characters into as many columns as the uniq characters

Tags: text-processing

So, I have a file like that:

- `file1`: three columns

  ```
  SNP Id Geno
  1 a AB
  2 a AB
  3 a BB
  . . .
  . . .
  . . .
  1 b AB
  2 b BB
  3 b AB
  . . .
  . . .
  . . .
  1 c AA
  2 c AB
  3 c AA
  . . .
  . . .
  . . .
  ```

and I need a file like that:

- `file2`: as many columns as the numbers of ID with their genotypes

  ```
  SNP Genoa Genob Genoc . . .
  1 AB AB AA
  2 AB BB AB
  3 BB AB AA
  . . . .
  . . . .
  . . . .
  ```

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help , add an explanation of how input becomes the expected output and add what you tried to solve this problem...

Comment: are those 3 dots `. . .` part of the content or just for shortening?

Comment: dots means that the file is big, like 50000 SNPs and hundreds Ids

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{g[$1] = g[$1] " " $3}
     END {for (i in g) print i g[i]}' < file1 > file2
```

Or to preserve the order:

```
awk '! ($1 in g) {snp[n++] = $1}
     {g[$1] = g[$1] " " $3}
     END {for (i = 0; i < n; i++) print snp[i] g[snp[i]]}' < file1 > file2
```

To include the "SNP Genoa Genob..." header:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {header = $1; prefix = $3; next}
     first == "" {first = "" $1}
     $1 == first {header = header " " prefix $2}
     ! ($1 in g) {snp[n++] = $1}
     {g[$1] = g[$1] " " $3}
     END {
       print header
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) print snp[i] g[snp[i]]
     }' < file1 > file2
```

Comment: I expanded your script to generate the missing header line as well. Maybe you can check it as I am no `awk` user.

Comment: @Philippos, looks like I missed that part of the requirements indeed. Your script looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

This script is neither slim nor readable, but it works and as opposed to the `awk` solution already posted it also generates the header line:

```
sed 'G;s/^SNP.*/SNP/
/^1 /s/ \([^ ]*\) .*SNP[^[:cntrl:]]*/& Geno\1/
s/^\([0-9]*\) [^ ]*\( [AB]*\)\n\(.*\n\1 [AB ]*\)/\3\2/
s/^\([0-9]*\) [^ ]*\( [AB]*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\4\3\1\2/
h
$!d' file1 > file2
```

Without being an `awk` user I guess you can expand the given `awk` solution like this to generate the header line as well:

```
awk '{if ($1==1) h=h" Geno"$2
if ($1!="SNP") g[$1]=g[$1]" "$3}
END {print "SNP"h; for (i in g) print i g[i]}' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '
   next if $. == 1;                                     # skip header
   $A[@A] = $F[1] if /^1\h/;                            # populate new header
   push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[2]}{$,="\t";                   # OFS = tab
   print q/SNP/, map { "Geno$_" } @A;                   # new header print
   print $_, @{$h{$_}} for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h;  # result
' gene.data
```

Here store the 3rd field `$F[2]` into an AoA (array_of_array).
At the end, we sort the hash keys numerically, and print the data.

```
sed -e '
   1d; # monospace lines
   s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/\t/g;s/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//
   H;g
   #  1   2                            3                     4
   s/\(\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\)1[[:blank:]]\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\([[:blank:]][^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)$/\tGeno\3\1\n1\4/
   /\(\n[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\)[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)$/s//\1\2/
   y/\n_/_\n/
   s/_\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\([^_]*\)_\(.*_\)\{0,1\}\1\([[:blank:]][^_]*\)/_\1\2\4_\3/
   y/\n_/_\n/
   h;$!d
   s/\n*$//
   s/\n\(\n\)/\1/
   s/^[[:blank:]]/SNP&/
' gene.data
```

---

### Result

```
SNP     Genoa   Genob   Genoc
1       AB      AB      AA
2       AB      BB      AB
3       BB      AB      AA
```

Comment: The following command did work: perl -lane ' push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[2]} {print "$_ @{$h{$_}}" for sort { $a <=> $c } keys %h' file1.txt > file2.txt

Comment: @LLVerardo Change the `$c` to `$b`. They are not randomly chosen.